# H2 and Hibernate (JPA) -> GenerationType.IDENTITY after persisting

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2

I use last H2 (current master) and Hibernate 5.14.14 as JPA provider. I have the following column in table:

```
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

and the following field in entity:

```
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
```

And this is my code:

```
//POINT A entity.getId() = null
entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.persist(entity);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
//POINT B entity.getId() = null.
```

My question - at point B according to JPA specification entity.getId() must return the value that database (H2) generated for this column (I mean next ID for the row) or null? I need to know, why I have null at point B - is the problem in H2/Hibernate or in my understanding of JPA.

Comment: Have you checked the database column ID value?

Comment: @AmanKumayu Yes, in database ID column has values (1,2,3) etc.

Comment: @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) is only supported by mysql